# Android Spinner: Populate Second Spinner Based on Selection of First

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-spinner

my requirement is to populate Second Spinner Based on Selection of First Spinner. My question is: Is it possible to have an XML file with node structure? For example something like this:

```
<Europe>
<State name="France">
     <city name="Paris"/>
     <city name="Lyon"/>
     <city name="Nice"/>
</State>
<State name="Spain">
     <city name="Madrid"/>
     <city name="Barcelona"/>
     <city name="Valencia"/>
</State>
<State name="Germany">
     <city name="Berlin"/>
     <city name="Frankfurt"/>
     <city name="Monaco"/>
</State>
</Europe>
```

How to do this? Please help me. thanks

Comment: Hint: Yes its possible,,,just parse this xml file and put it in ArrayList and set it to second spinner

Comment: Thanks Samir.. after parsing the xml I will have in the first spinner the state name and in the second the related city linked to selected state? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an onItemSelectedListener and updating the adapter contents of the second spinner based on the values selected, for example:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

//setup initial adapters etc.

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
       //based on the selected item update the second spinner:
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

You can also have a custom adapter for your spinner 2 with an **updateItems(List items)** method to take care of the items changes for example the method would look something like:

```
    public void updateItems(List<String> items){
      currentItems.clear();
      currentItems.addAll(items);
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```